# why local time dosen't work? POSIXct in specific time zone [R]

Tags: r, timezone, posixlt

the time my data are in `EST` time zone, and I try to use this time zone.

I want to count the week (in local time, not `GMT`), so I manually define an `originTime` in `EDT`

```
originTime = as.POSIXlt('2000-01-02 00:00:00 EDT')
dt2 = data.frame(time=c(as.POSIXlt('2000-01-09 00:00:05 EDT')))
dt2$week = as.integer( floor( ( as.numeric(dt2$time) - as.numeric(originTime) ) /(3600*24*7) ) )
dt2$wday = weekdays(dt2$time)
```

This works.

Now I want to find out, what's one week after a given time?

```
> as.POSIXlt( 1 * 3600*24*7 , origin = originTime)
[1] "2000-01-08 19:00:00 EST"
```

Here's the problem, R seems to think `originTime` is in `GMT`. Can somebody help? Thanks

Comment: sorry missed a line of code. See OP please @ Richard Scriven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two serious problems. EDT does not really exist, and even if it did it would not be appropriate for a January date. The (US) Eastern timezone is "EST5EDT" to make it distinct from the Ozzie EST. (Furthermore these may be different on different OSes.) Safest would be `tz="America/New_York"`.  For data entry, you need to use the 'tz' parameter AND change the default (FALSE) setting of 'usetz':

```
(originTime = as.POSIXlt('2000-01-02 00:00:00', format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
                          tz="EST5EDT", usetz=TRUE) )
[1] "2000-01-02 EST"
```

A test using "%Z" which is only for output:

```
> format( as.POSIXlt('2000-01-02 00:00:00', format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", 
                                            tz="America/New_York", usetz=TRUE) ,
         format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z")
[1] "2000-01-02 00:00:00 EST"
```

I've never used the origin argument in as.POSIXlt so cannot really explain why it fails to deliver the expected result I've always used `+.POSIXt` or `seq.POSIXt` to construct intervals:

```
format(as.POSIXlt('2000-01-02 00:00:00', tz="America/New_York", usetz=TRUE)+ 1*3600*24*7, 
       format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z")  #  %Z is only used for output
 # [1] "2000-01-09 00:00:00 EST"   A week later at midnight.
```

I think the reason one needs to force a time printing with a format argument is that midnight-times are shortened to just printing the date with no further H:M:S information.

Comment: You can also use `tz="US/Eastern"`

Comment: I agree that main issue here is timestamp is incorrectly formatted. An important point in this answer too is that EST and EDT are not zones but offsets from UTC (-5 and -4, respectively). The great thing about specifying a zone is that the offsets are automatically applied based on local time in a given zone.  But if for some reason your time is in EDT during Jan. then you would want to use `%Z` format within `as.POSIXlt` to specify the offset from UTC rather than zone.

Comment: Ah, yes. An example of "States rights", a hallowed Murkin tradition.  On my machine there is a `../zoneinfo/US/ directory` whose contents are: `"Alaska" ,"Central", "Hawaii", "Mountain", "Samoa", "Aleutian", "East-Indiana", "Indiana-Starke", "Pacific", "Arizona", "Eastern", "Michigan", "Pacific-New"`

Comment: Hi thanks @BondedDust. I tried `originTime = as.POSIXlt('2000-01-02 00:00:00', tz="EST5EDT", usetz=T)`   `as.POSIXlt( 1 * 3600*24*7 , origin = originTime)` and the result is still `[1] "2000-01-08 19:00:00 EST"`  Do you know how to fix this? thank you!

Comment: Try using the `"+"`-function. It has a POSIXt method: `format(as.POSIXlt('2000-01-02 00:00:00', tz="America/New_York", usetz=TRUE)+1 * 3600*24*7, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z") #
[1] "2000-01-09 00:00:00 EST"`